# How do we solve the plugin activation error in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

> The plugin generated 1 characters of unexpected output during
>   activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems
>   with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing
>   this plugin.

While activating the plugin in wordpress i got the above error.
Don't know why it's happening.
Kindly suggest some ideas.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plugin is outputing something on activation. Validate that the included PHP files have no extra whitespace outside the `<?php ?>` tags and make sure there's no printing happening anywhere.

A hacky solution is to use `ob_start()` and `ob_end_clean()` during the activation. It might hide it but it really doesn't fix the problem.

Plugin activation and deactivation processes should not print anything from PHP. If you need to get some info out of the process consider logging.

If the plugin is not yours, try to contact the original developer about the issue.

Comment: Thanks.. i fixed it.. Whitespace problem..Thank yu for your response